# Excel 2016: transposing data from 1 table to another using formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to transpose my text from table A to table B. Is there a quick formula that lets me do it?

Table A is actually a set of responses I have collected through a survey where I would ask the evaluee to nominate 3 evaluators. For example: Tom wants to nominate James, John and Mary.

Table B is what I want to achieve, where the first column is the evaluator, and the following columns are the people they have to evaluate (evaluee). For example: Jim needs to evaluate Tom.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You write "Table B is what I want to achieve" - but shown TableB data is NOT related to shown TableA data. They MUST match! by 100%. If not nobody can understand how it is done.

Comment: Cannot find the relationship between 2 tables, could you provide more information?

Comment: I tend to agree. I can't see the relationship between the two tables so it's hard to provide a suggestion.

Comment: Since Jim is not listed in Table A, how do we know that he should be listed in Table B as an Evaluator of Tom.  And why do you have identical names listed as evaluators in Table B?